# Laravel Eloquent (eager loadable) custom polymorphic relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

Using Eloquent, I'm trying to make a polymorphic relationship between some models that isn't working out. Simplified, it works like this: there is a model 'groups', which obviously can contain some groups. Now each of these groups can either contain 'members' or 'guests', so I have a table and model for both of them. These are not similar to each other. My groups table contains a column in which model to use (members or guests). The structure is as follows:

```
groups (\App\Models\Group)
    id
    name
    model (either \App\Models\Member or \App\Models\Guest)

members (\App\Models\Member)
    id
    group_id
    first_name
    last_name
    address
    email
    .....

guests (\App\Models\Guest)
    id
    group_id
    name
```

So the relationship 'people' in a group retrieves either the members or the guests. Using the default `$this->morphTo()` function using the group_id is able to retrieve the correct results, but due to its logic only returns one result, while I need all results. The rest of the app is indifferent to whether the people are members or guests, so I do not want to split those two up here.

Any ideas on how to accomplish this? I'm trying to eager load the relationship.

Comment: Can you answer a question wich will give us some insight. if a group is empty, is it a member group or a guest group ? maybe you just need an intermediary model `People` between `Group` and `Member`/`Guest` with a polymorphic relation to them.

Comment: I have been thinking about that as well, but I was not able yet to think that out. A group should normally not be empty, but in any case it defaults to a guest group. I only have one `Member` group and zero or more `Guest` groups. Any group that gets added has to be a `Guest` group.

Comment: Then you have bigger structural issues, the member group could be replaced with a simple attribute in the member entity, either in the group or not.

Comment: I ended up making a variation on the morphTo relation, which returns a collection instead of the first item, which works great. But indeed it's not the best structure, I might eventually just change this construction.